# Visual Studio extensions for code generation...what's the best way

Tags: visual-studio

So we have this tool, it's a web page, we drop a large piece of text in textBox a (say sql) run the tool
and it generates the guts of a code file in TextBoxb (say a custom view class model).

it's written in C#.

I know there are several ways to create visual studio extensions.

What I'd like to know is, what's the best/easiest/fastest way to take a c# dll that has a method that takes text in and returns text out, and turn it into a VisualStudio extenson, that takes text in and creates a files, adds it to the project and puts the text into it.

We're using Vs2008 and VS2010, and I'm okay the best soloution only work on 2010.

The closest I've found by googling so far is this:
http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/03/01/generate-code-from-custom-file-formats.aspx
but they are for custom file formats only, i want to generate*.cs and *.rdlc and similar files.
I'd also like to be able to add methods to an existing class.

tutorial walkthroughs or better approaches woud be greatly appreicated.

Comment: Off the top the easiest approach to extention writting in many cases is using MEF or you may just be able to use a T4Template instead if code generation is your only requirement but, that could be a bit more difficult. But I'm not totally clear on exactly how your extension is to work.

Comment: So you are taking a web form and placing text in a text box on the form. That text is actually the code you wish to incorporate in your generator. Past that something gets put into a dll and run in .NET?

Comment: well for example, we paste in the SQL to retreive the object, and the the generator cals the sql and write the code for the CustomView Class for that retreive. then that is used to generate the Controller methods, the View etc. all classes and snippets of code get generated, then all we have to is write our custom Buissness objects and make and cusomt changes to the View.

Comment: So for your example you would return a dll that contains an implementation of a common interface that when used runs the SQL given? Or am I off?

Comment: Oh sorry just saw the first part of your comment

Comment: Well i am still not really sure what it is you are wanting to do but.... for code generation i recommend t4 templates http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx, for SQL Object Relational Mapping, use the Entity Framework http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework, and for the simplest way to write an extension for Visual Studio (provided you have vs 2010 ) use MEF http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/VSIPMarketing/VSX101-An-Introduction-to-Visual-Studio-2010-Extensibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS package Builder is the answer. Lots easier.